# pass query to execute to a jdbc component

Tags: spring-integration

How can I have a jdbc channel adapter of gateway to execute a query that is passed through input message or its properties. Not sure if there a way to use query this way. So instead of below

```
<int-jdbc:outbound..
        query="select * from ...." 
        ...
```

I would like to have something like

```
<int-jdbc:outbound... 
        query="payload.sqlQuery" 
        ..>
```

Thank you for your help.
We have a flow where the adapter need to run various queries as specified by  request so i can not put the query there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it isn't possible by adapters. They aren't designed for such a low-level protocol linking. It breaks a bit `messaging` principles.

If you really need so generic behavior of the Integration endpoint, consider to use `JdbcTemplate` directly from some POJO and refer it to the `<service-activator>`.